# Find out If user is loged in (Laravel) in frontend

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.5

so I come to you with a simple question: how is laravel session relay working.

My use Case: I have a laravel site cached with a varnish like so :

1. every get request is made as the user is not logged in
2. any user related info if loaded via ajax after the user loaded the page.

My problem is that I need to know in my front end if a user is logged in.

Things that I noticed:

1. Laravel session is not accessible in js
2. Laravel session is there even if the user is not logged in

I also tried to set my own cookie on login and unset it in on logout, but it my cookie is randomly diapering while the user is still logged in.

If someone has any idea on how to find out if my user is logged in from the standard cookies I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [pass the data to JS](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes) like I'm showing in my repo. For example:

```
<input id="authenticated" type="hidden" value="{{ auth()->check() }}">
```

And then get the data which will be `true` or `false`:

```
let authenticated = $('#authenticated').val();
```

Alternatively, you could use an Ajax call and execute `auth()->check()` in a controller method.

Comment: i cant relay do that since any html is cached  and  the input will always be set false.That whould have worked(and will work) if would have varnish between server and the client

Comment: @FlorentinStemate "HTML is cached" sounds like a problem you should fix that. But if you don't want to do that for some reason, you can just make an Ajax call and execute `auth()->check()` in a controller method.

Comment: i did not downvote you,i upvoted, that its a very good approach. And yeah i think your ideea is good i would have loved to have a way to check  without another ajax request

Comment: @FlorentinStemate well, you have only two choices here. To pass the data through HTML (like I've shown or within `<script></script>`) or make an Ajax call. There is no any other way.

Comment: The solution is not good because we dont want to touch the server. the website is a news website with possibly very large traffic. So if we can identify from the LARAVEL session if user is logged or not we might save thousands of requests.

Comment: Also the question is how the Laravel session is working? Because it a crucial issue and I would like to go and investigate if really is any way to do this. Laravel knows from the cookie - we should be able to know too.. maybe... so how does Laravel knows from the cookie if user is logged or not?

Comment: @alextoader Laravel uses DB or file or cookies etc to store the session data. But you can't read the cookie because it's encrypted. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use in JS   `var userCheck= " <?php echo Auth::check();?> ";` , then check if userCheck is equal to one then user is logged In otherwise not.

Comment: I have all html cached  as if the user is not logged in so that will always be false since after the first request all subsequent requests   will not hit Laravel but the Varnish server

Comment: if HTML is cached then, answer of @Alexey Mezenin will also do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a token whenever a user is logged in and send it to the front-end and save it in the cookie. The cookie can have and the expiry time of say 5 hours. If during these 5 hours, user sends some requests, then the token is refreshed and 5 hour time starts again. In case, no request comes to the backend it means user is not active and you can log him out.

Comment: A session cookie can be generated even when a user is not logged in, so checking if there's a session cookie isn't sufficient.